# Azure DB Connection string - Failed to Authenticate

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure for the first time and ran into a problem if anyone can help.
I have a asp.net project that i created and used local storage till now. I create a student account on azure and created my first database, however when I try and connect to it i get this error:

```
Failed to authenticate the user [my user name] in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).
Error code 0xinvalid_grant
AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '022907d3-0f1b-48f7-badc-1ba6abab6d66'. Trace ID: 47fb1edc-221a-418b-bdd0-3375701b4600 Correlation ID: c0970262-82b4-45e8-a805-decd5e4b3799 Timestamp: 2023-11-06 15:01:15Z
```

I used this connection string:
ADO.NET (Microsoft Entra password authentication)

```
Server=tcp:dev-bloggr.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DevBloggr;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";
```

And the username and password is the same as i use to log in to azure.

I can connect to this db using Microsoft SQL studio using the db name with the username and password but i have to authenticate with microsoft authenticator app using my phone so i think that is a problem. Does anyone know how i can make this work?

Ps. When I check my roles for the resource group then i can see i am the owner and have all access.
Thanks!

Comment: Typically in a web app (or any app with a middle layer) you don't use your account to authenticate to the db, you use a managed identity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cefcore%2Cdotnet

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to connect to the Azure SQL database with Active Directory password authentication using the connection string below:

```
Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";
```

I faced the same error. As per [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/raising-the-baseline-security-for-all-organizations-in-the-world/ba-p/3299048), MFA is the default method of login for all Azure tenants. So, I modified the connection string with Authentication="Active Directory Interactive":

```
Server=tcp:dbservere.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Interactive";
```

When I ran the app with the above connection string, it opened a browser for authentication. After authentication, it displayed as below:

[image]

And it returned the query output as shown below:

[image]